# Is it good or bad practice to design your code to treat an empty collection and a null value differently?

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections

Part of the project I'm working on got updated, and at some point somebody started sending empty collections instead of `null` as arguments to a method.

This led to a single bug first, which then led me to change `if (null == myCollection)` with `if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(myCollection))`, which in the end led to a cascade of several bugs. This way I discovered that a lot of the code treats these collections differently:

- when a collection is empty (i.e. the user specifically wanted to have *nothing* here)
- when a collection is `null` (i.e. the user did not mention anything here)

Hence, my question: is this good or bad design practice?

Comment: It depends.....

Comment: It depends on your use case/code design etc. I would prefer always do a null check ONLY but if my logic remains same for collection being NULL or empty, I would use the library method:CollectionUtils.isEmpty(myCollection)

Comment: There are pros and cons, and you need to weigh them yourself (yourselves). Nulls typically have a bit of bad smell overall, but if there is no good way to avoid the possibility of sending null, your way doesn’t sound too bad to me.

Comment: It never makes sense in case of a collection to return NULL instead of an empty colection. Rather throw an exception if execution or generating the collection is not possible (e.g. ArgumentException). This is more meaningful than just returning NULL.

Comment: @MauricePerry It depends on _what_ exactly?? Good answer. Very random.

Comment: @OleV.V. when `getPersons()`returns a collection of `person` under which circumstances would you expect the collection to be NULL? If there are no persons then the collection is empty. The caller then knows 'aha, no persons found'. What does NULL mean to the caller? Nothing. In case of an error you'd better throw an exception. This is more meaningful.

Comment: @BionicCode Maybe I forgot to mention: IMHO it will have to be a very clear prerequisite that the meaning of `null` is clearly documented. As I understood the question, `null` would not mean error but rather something like “not known”.

Comment: @OleV.V. The question is tagged 'Java' and Java is a strongly typed language. When a method is declared to return a collection, then how can the return value be unknown? It's always known. You can document that the return value can be NULL, but in case of a collection this never  makes sense. It just makes you application less robust and error prone. A collection is an aggregation of Types. It can be either empty or populated by at least one element. What other state do you require? No result means no elements in the collection. That's clear to everybody without reading any documentaion.

Comment: @OleV.V. In case of collections we can say Null is always avoidable. When somebody returns NULL this just expresses sloppy and dangerous code, that can return some undefined object references to the caller. Why this has to be? If your class or method is in an undefined state your application becomes unpredictable. That's when throwing an exception is appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In his (very good) book *Effective Java*, Joshua Bloch treats this question for the returned values of methods (not "in general" like your question) :

> (*About use of null*) It is errorprone, because the programmer writing
> the client might forget to write the special case code to handle a null
> return.
>
> (...)
>
> It is sometimes argued that a null return value is preferable to an
> empty array because it avoids the expense of allocating the array.
> This argument fails on two counts. First, it is inadvisable to worry
> about performance at this level unless profiling has shown that the
> method in question is a real contributor to performance problems (Item
> 55). Second, it is possible to return the same zero-length array from every invocation that returns no items because
> zero-length arrays are immutable and immutable objects may be shared
> freely (Item 15).
>
> (...)
>
> In summary, **there is no reason ever to return null from an
> array- or collection-valued method instead of returning an empty array
> or collection.** (...)

Personnally I use this reasoning as a rule of thumb with any use of Collections in my code. Of course, there is some case where a distinction between null and empty makes sense but in my experience it's quite rare.

Nevertheless, as stated by BionicCode in the comments section, in the case of a method that returns null instead of empty to specify that *something went wrong*, you always have the possibility of throwing an exception instead.

Comment: It never makes sense in case of a collection to return NULL instead of an empty colection. Rather throw an exception if execution or generating the collection is not possible (e.g. ArgumentException). This is more meaningful than just returning NULL.

Comment: If you would add the option to throw an exception in an error situation instead of returning NULL to your answer, then I would give you an upvote. NULL is absolutely avoidable in this rendered situation. And it must be avoided for the sake of readable and meaningful code and most of all robustness.

Comment: @BionicCode good point, I added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Because of the yellow box and the last bold lines inside it, you deserve more upvotes. But it seems like the idea is too difficult to grasp or it is too  painful to break with old  habits and therefore easier to deny it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question already has an accepted answer. But because of the discussions I had, I decided to write my own to address this problem.

The inventor of NULL himself Mr. Tony Hoare says

> I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null reference in 1965. At that time, I was designing the first comprehensive type system for references in an object oriented language (ALGOL W). My goal was to ensure that all use of references should be absolutely safe, with checking performed automatically by the compiler. But I couldn’t resist the temptation to put in a null reference, simply because it was so easy to implement. This has led to innumerable errors, vulnerabilities, and system crashes, which have probably caused a billion dollars of pain and damage in the last forty years.

First of all it is very bad practice to introduce breaking changes when updating old code that was already released and tested. Refactoring in this situation is always dangerous and should be avoided. I know that it can hurt to release ugly or stupid code, but if this happened, then this is a clear sign of a lack of quality management tools (e.g. code reviews or conventions). But obviously there were no unit tests otherwise the changes would have been reverted immediately by the author of the changes, due to the failing tests. The main problem is that your team has no conventions how to handle NULL as argument or as result. The intention of the author of the update to switch from NULL arguments to empty collections is absolutely right and should be supported, but he shouldn't have done it for working code and he should have discussed with the team, so that the rest of the team can follow in order to make it more effective. Your Team definitely must come together and agree on abandoning NULL as an argument or result value or at least find a standard. Better send NULL to hell. Your only solution is to revert the changes done by the author of the update (I assume you are using version control). Then redo the update, but do it the old fashioned and nasty way using NULL like you were doing it before. Don't use NULL in new code - for a brighter future. Trying to fix the updated version will escalate the situation for sure and therefore will waste time. (I assume that we are talking about a bigger project). Roll back to the previous version if possible.

To make it short if you don't like to continue reading: yes it's *very* bad practice. You yourself can draw this conclusion from the situation you are in now. You now witness very unstable and unpredictable code. The irrational bugs are the proof that your code has become unpredictable. If you don't have unit tests for at least the business logic then the code is hot iron. The practice that has lead to this code can never be good. NULL has no intuitional meaning to the user of an API, when there is the possibility to get a neutral result or parameter (like this is the case with a collection). An empty collection is neutral. You can expect a collection to be empty or to contain at least one element. There is noting else you can expect from a collection. You want to indicate an error and that an operation couldn't terminate? Then prefer to throw an exception with a good name that communicates the root of the error clearly to the caller.

NULL is a historical relic. Stumbling over a NULL value meant that the programmer wrote sloppy code. He forgot to initialize a pointer by assigning a memory address to it. The compiler must know a memory address as a reference in order to create a valid pointer. If you wanted a pointer but don't waste memory for just declaring the pointer or didn't know the address to this point, NULL was a convention to have the pointer to point to nowhere, which means no memory must be allocated for the pointer's reference (except for the pointer itself). Today in modern OO-Languages with garbage collection and plenty of available memory, NULL has become irrelevant in programming. There are situations  where it is used to express e.g. the absence of data like in SQL. But in OO programming you can absolutely avoid it and therefore make your application more robust.

You have the choice to apply the Null-Object Pattern. Also it is best practice to either use default parameters (if your language like C# supports this) or use overloads. E.g. if the method parameter is optional then use an overload (or a default parameter). If the parameter is mandatory but you can't provide the value, then simply don't call the method. If the parameter is a collection, then always use an empty collection whenever you have no values. The author of the method must handle this case as he must handle all possible cases or parameter states. This includes NULL. So it's the duty of the method's author to check for NULL and to decide how to handle it. Here kicks the convention in. If your  team agreed on to never use NULL, this annoying and ugly NULL checks are not required anymore. Some frameworks offer a `@NotNull` attribute. The author can use it to decorate the method parameters to indicate that NULL is not a valid value. The compiler will now do the NULL checks and show an error to the programmer that (mis)uses the method and simply won't compile. Alongside code reviews, this can help to prevent or identify violations and lead to more robust code.

Most libraries provide helper classes e.g. `Array.Empty()` or `Enumerable.Empty()` (C#) to create empty collections that provide methods like `IsEmpty()`. This makes intentions semantically clear and code therefore nice to read. It's worth it to write your own helper if none exist in your standard library.

Try to integrate quality management into your team's routine. Do code reviews to make sure the code to be released is conform to your quality standards (unit tests, no NULL values, always use curly braces for statement bodies, naming, etc...)

I hope you can fix your problem. I know this is a stressful situation to clean up the mess of somebody else. This is why communication in teams is so important.

Comment: We agree about a lot more than I thought at first. Thank you for a thorough and wise answer.

Comment: "If null did not exist, it would be necessary to invent it." (Apologies to Voltaire.)

Comment: @StuartMarks Thank you, that's a good one. How do you like this one: "And don't tell me there isn't one bit of difference between null and space, because that's exactly how much difference there is."
*Larry Wall* - check the table

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs. Null is definitele not empty collection. I'd say that it is a bad practice to treat separately empty and not empty collection. 
Null howver indicates a kind of lack of data. I'd say that if such situation is legal and you are using java 8 or higher you should probably use Optional. In this case Optional.empty() means that there is no collection while Optional.of(collection) means that collection is here even if it itself is empty.

Comment: I’d use `Optional` only if it’s a return value from a method. From the question it doesn’t sound like it’s the case here. Otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: In addition: if OP uses Java 7 or an even older version, then (s)he could use a library like Guava to get access to `Optional` and its features.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to return NULL instead of an empty collection. If I invoke a method to return me a set of objects and there are no objects to return, then the result collection remains empty. This is semantically more correct and expected by every caller. When the method cannot execute due to e.g. incorrect parameters, you better throw an ArgumentException than returning NULL.

Comment: NULL is almost never necessary and not an intended or expected result. NULL means no memory allocated or a reference that is not initialized (pointing to nowhere). The method must ensure that all returned objects are correctly initialized or throw an exception if initialization is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use like this in case of collection.

```
if(myCollection !=null && !myCollection.isEmpty()) {

//Process the logic

}
```

However as part of design, Joshua Bloch recommends to use empty collection in Effective Java.

To quote his statement,

> there is no reason ever to return null from an array-valued method
>   instead of returning a zero-length array.

You can find the link for effective java.
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321356683](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

Answer (score 1):

well, by accessing a null value, you can get a NullPointerException directly, and most times (from my experience) it is bad practice to make a difference between a null value and empty collection in deeper hierarchy of the logic. it should just be empty instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s put some downvote bait here, shall we? As I understand it, you have got a method like

```
public void foo(Collection myCollection) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(myCollection)) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I also understand that this method is called from many places so it would most practical if you don’t need to change all the calls. And I understand that there is *a semantic difference* between passing null and passing an empty collection to it. An empty collection means that we know for a fact that there are no elements. Null means that it is not specified whether there are any (and I am assuming that your method is able to do useful work in this case too).

The nice design would have two methods:

```
/** @param myCollection a possibly empty collection; not null */
public void foo(Collection myCollection);

/** Call this method if you don’t want to specify elements */
public void foo();
```

However, considering your existing code base, you don’t want to introduce the non-null requirement mentioned all of a sudden and break code that has been working until now. One way forward would be to introduce a comment on the 1-arg method effectively saying

> Passing null to this method is deprecated. It works but may be
>   prohibited in a future version.

This will buy you time to change the code base over the coming months or even years and still allow you to arrive at the better design at some point.

At the same time you may change your 1-arg method to just delegating to the no-arg method if it receives a null.

Caveat: You need to be very clear in your documentation (Javadoc) about the semantics of not specifying elements (ideally calling the no-arg method) and the semantic difference from passing an empty collection.

Comment: You really don't need a 'no-arg' overload. Why can't you just pass an empty collection to the method? `foo(new Collection()` doesn't work? Who is responsible for this? It's you. You only have to change your style of writing code and avoid passing around undefined object references. It's not about documenting that not-null is a requirement or what null means. It's about your mind set. Collections are the easiest situation to handle.

Comment: Situation 1: a method needs a collection of elements to operate on, but you don't have any? Then either don't call the method or just pass in an empty collection. Situation two: a method must return a collection as a result of the operation but there are no elements to return or the method for some reason can't operate? Then either don't return anything and throw a meaningful exception or return an empty collection. As a result you don't need to clutter and pollute your code with ugly NULL checks anymore and obviously your application has become more robust.

Comment: So it's not a question of design to solve this issue, it's about the programmer's discipline and thoughtfulness.

Comment: Many frameworks offer a `@NotNull` attribute which the writer of the API can use to decorate method parameters and fields. The intent is to force the programmer to stick to the best practice. Otherwise you will get a compiler error. Too sad that this attributes are necessary, since it should be natural to stay away from NULL since NULL is a serious exception itself. It used to mean that a programmer worked sloppy and forgot to assign a memory address to a pointer or that the memory the pointer was referencing is no longer allocated.

Comment: And most languages offer helper methods like `Array.Empty()` or `Collection.Empty()` to emphasize the empty collection value to the reader. It is so nice to read because the intend is so clear.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for the long follow-up. Had I interpreted the question the way you have, I would have agreed with everything you've said. Everything. I read the question differently. Only the questioner can tell who if us read it as intended. I have tried to specify my interpretation and assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I think we both understood the question the same way. I wasn't answering his question. I was commenting on answers that in my opinion should have emphasized that NULL is always a bad practice. It is because of NULL that he has all the problems. If there wasn't  NULL, all intentions of any method would be clear(er). I'm saying the problem is more complex than just providing overloads. His team needs better communication and quality standards (abandon NULL is one of them). I wrote an answer so I don't need to pollute yours. Please feel free to add your opinion on this.

Comment: And I was was always referring to collections because the question was specifically about collections. I always emphasized this. If the parameter is a different object than a collection overloading makes sense. Hope you understand my point